# SAP HYBRIS [Y] : How to restrict a customersupportagentrole user from cancelling or returning orders

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I created a user and assigned it as customersupportagentrole, 
This user logs as customersupportagentrole to backoffice
I want this user to see the orders but not to manipulate them,
For example canceling or returning orders.
I am tinkering 'Permission Management - null ( [customersupportagentgroup])'
section. Even i disable all selections related with return & order,
this user can still cancel an order, or return it.
Is there a way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable cancel/return order buttons, you must change canPerform() method of your order actions/return actions. Canperform()  provide that visible or invisible according to your  choice. You can check user's role in this method. If user's role equals to 'customersupportagentrole', you can disable this button.